# Replace dots with commas in google app script

Tags: javascript, replace

i need help raplacing dots with commas with this script;

```
function doPost(e) {
  //Return if null  
  if( e == undefined ) {
    console.log("no data");
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("need data");
  }
  //Parse the JSON data
  var event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var data = event.data;
  var price = event.data;
  var at = event.data;
  //Get the last row without data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var column = sheet.getRange("C1:C");
  var columnn = sheet.getRange("E1:E");
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  //Insert the data into the sheet
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(event.price);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(event.at); 
  column.setNumberFormat("@");
  columnn.setNumberFormat("@");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
  
  }
```

price and at is coming as eg:347.7100 but i need it as 347,7100

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ciao you could try `replace` function like:

```
function doPost(e) {
  //Return if null  
  if( e == undefined ) {
    console.log("no data");
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("need data");
  }
  //Parse the JSON data
  var event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var data = event.data;
  var price = event.data.replace('.', ',');
  var at = event.data.replace('.', ',');
  //Get the last row without data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var column = sheet.getRange("C1:C");
  var columnn = sheet.getRange("E1:E");
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  //Insert the data into the sheet
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(event.price);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(event.at); 
  column.setNumberFormat("@");
  columnn.setNumberFormat("@");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
  
  }
```

Note: `replace` works only with string. If `at` and/or `price` are not strings, you have to parse before apply `replace` like:

```
...
var price = String(event.data).replace('.', ',');
var at = String(event.data).replace('.', ',');
...
```

Comment: Ok i'll try that out! Thanks for fast answer 